# Loading File using PFImageView on iOS 8 returning an Error

Tags: ios, parse-platform

This works on iOS 7, but not iOS 8. I am using version 1.4 of Parse.

```
imageView.file = (PFFile *)object[@"image"];

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)
```

Comment: How about this? `imageView.file = (PFFile*)[object objectForKey@"image"];`

Comment: That didn't change anything. Didn't expect it to.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with that line of code then. Could you give more context of your app?

Comment: I don't think the context matters here. I think it has something to do with v1.4 of their iOS SDK. http://blog.parse.com/2014/09/18/parse-sdk-for-ios-8-performance-and-security/

Comment: I'm using the new SDK in my iOS app along with PFFiles and it doesn't give me these errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it:

```
pfImageView.file = object[@"image"];
[pfImageView loadInBackground];
```

And please make sure there's a `object` and that this `object` has a `PFFile` in the column `image`.

If the above doesn't work, please send more code on how you are retrieving the `object`.